# adding silent audio in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to use ffmpeg to add a silent audio track to a MOV file.

I created a silent audio track longer than the video, and intend to use the -shortest option with ffmpeg.

Using SoX v14.3.1, I run this to generate a wav file:

```
sox -n -r 44100 -b 16 -c 2 -L silence.wav trim 0.0 60.000

# -n  = Sox's null file
# -r = sample rate 
# -b = bits per sample
# -c = num of channels
# -L = little endian
# filename
# trim - is an effect, args start and length.
```

My basic ffmpeg command looks like this:

```
ffmpeg -shortest \
-i silence.wav -acodec pcm_s16le \
-i vid_no_sound.mov -vcodec copy vid_with_sound.mov
```

The result of this is:

```
ffmpeg version 0.11.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 27 2012 13:11:25 with gcc 4.4.5
  configuration: --extra-cflags=-static --prefix=/root/ffmpeg_build/src/ffmpeg-0.11.1 --enable-bzlib --enable-gnutls --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-openssl --enable-zlib --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-version3
  libavutil      51. 54.100 / 51. 54.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.100 / 54.  6.100
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 77.100 /  2. 77.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
[wav @ 0x29ab2e0] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5015510
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'silence.wav':
  Duration: 00:01:00.00, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Input #1, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'vid_no_sound.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 537199360
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2012-07-25 13:41:44
  Duration: 00:00:14.50, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 27457 kb/s
    Stream #1:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24, 1920x1080, 27450 kb/s, SAR 1920:1920 DAR 16:9, 24 fps, 24 tbr, 24 tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-07-25 13:41:44
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #1:1(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-07-25 13:42:06
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 00:00:00:00
File 'vid_with_sound.mov' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
auto-inserting filter 'auto-inserted resampler 0' between the filter 'src' and the filter 'aformat'
[aresample @ 0x2ab3b00] chl:stereo fmt:s16 r:44100Hz -> chl:stereo fmt:flt r:44100Hz
[NULL @ 0x2994320] Codec is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, try -strict -2
Output #0, mov, to 'vid_with_sound.mov':
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: qtrle (rle  / 0x20656C72), rgb24, 1920x1080 [SAR 1920:1920 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 27450 kb/s, 24 fps, 90k tbn, 24 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2012-07-25 13:41:44
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:1: Audio: none, 44100 Hz, stereo, flt, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #1:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:1 (pcm_s16le -> aac)
Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:1 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
```

I have tried adding the `-strict -2` as suggested, although I am not sure where to put it in the command line.

I've spent two hours trying different things and reading ffmpeg documentation, but I'm still stuck.

How do I add a silent audio track to a mov file?

Answer (score 159, accepted):

## [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) audio filter

You can use `ffmpeg` to create the silent audio and combine it with a video in one step. This example will use the [anullsrc audio filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) to generate stereo silent audio with a sample rate of 44100:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i video.mov -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest output.mov
```

- `channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100` is the default, but I included it just as an example of how to use these options.

### Ignoring existing audio

If your video input file has audio that you want to ignore then use the [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) option to override the default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i video.mov -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:a -map 1:v -shortest output.mp4
```

- `-map 0:a -map 1:v` can be translated as: from the first input (`0`) use the audio (`a`), and from the second input (`1`) use the video (`v`).

---

#### Notes

- These examples will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the video so it does not get re-encoded (like a "copy and paste").
- It is always recommended to use a recent `ffmpeg`. Links to recent builds are on the [FFmpeg Download](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page or you can refer to a step-by-step [guide to compile `ffmpeg`](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).

Comment: `/dev/zero` works in `avconv` too, but `-f lavfi` doesn't seem to. Don't forget the `-shortest` flag, or it will sit there forever encoding silence.

Comment: if i want to just add silent where audio not available then what to do ? for example when recording desktop audio ?

Comment: @Ahmad Sorry, but I don't understand your question.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I am saying that i am recording desktop audio from virtual-audio-capturer and it start desktop recording when desktop producing some sound so is it possible to create silent sound while sound is not coming from desktop or any method which create silent audio all the while recording happens and record desktop as well

Comment: It's not very clear from the original post but it seems by saying "I created a silent audio track longer than the video" they meant they want to append some silence to the end of an existing movie.

This is exactly what I am looking for while keeping the last movie frame as is.  So how would you appending 2 seconds silence an existing .MP4 ? thank you.

Comment: @Marie That is worth asking as a new question because the solution is different.

Comment: @llogan posted question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60133816/how-to-append-2-seconds-of-silence-to-an-existing-movie-mp4-with-ffmpeg
Thank you.

Comment: @llogan could you please explain what "-f lavfi" does ?

Comment: You can use `ffprobe` to find the audio format (channels and sample rate) of your video.

Comment: why the `-shortest` in `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -i video.mov -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0:a -map 1:v -shortest output.mp4`? Removing `-shortest` from the command and using a 2024 *ffmpeg 6* release, I haven't had any issues with "*forever encoding silence*" as @z0r may have hinted at.

Comment: @Abdull Because the answer is from 2012, and z0r's comment is from 2014. And probably most ffmpeg installations are outdated.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a command for the [latest ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), works with MP4 (H264/AVC):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -i input.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -map 0 -map 1:v -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: what if when i want to add silent audio where audio not available ?

Answer (score 8):

Create video from image or convert image into video then add slient audio using ffmpeg.

You can use the anullsrc audio source filter in ffmpeg. Example to make a 5.1 channel, 48000 Hz sample rate, 10 seconds silent video file from image:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i img002.jpg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=5.1:sample_rate=48000 -t 10 -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vf scale=480:320 -y output.mp4
```

> img002.jpg: Input image file
>
> -i anullsrc: Add silent audio
>
> -t 10: Number of seconds
>
> scale=480:320: Video resolution width=420 and height=320
>
> -y: Overwrite existing output file
>
> output.mp4: Output file

Comment: Is there any way to do this in a filter_complex for an intermediate output?

Comment: @ed22 yes, surely! anullsrc can be used in a filter_complex chain. `-filter_complex "... anullsrc=cl=mono:r=44100[silence] ..."` I believe that is what you're looking for?

Comment: Here's an example usage which I had tried: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]scale=1920:1080[video_out]; anullsrc=cl=mono:r=44100[audio_out]" -map [video_out] -map [audio_out] -shortest output.mp4`

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I found so far for ffmpeg ver > 4.2:

**Add silence in the beginning:**

```
ffmpeg -i audio_in.wav -af areverse,apad=pad_dur=1s,areverse audio_out.wav
```

**Add silence at the end:**

```
ffmpeg -i audio_in.wav -af apad=pad_dur=1s audio_out.wav
```

This will add silence of 1 second to the audio.

Comment: From https://superuser.com/a/579110/19792, it looks like you can use `adelay` to prepend silence.  Note, this question is about adding a silent audio track, but your answer will probably be useful for many searchers.

Comment: strangely this `areverse,apad,areverse` approach is the only thing that works for me. im using ffmpeg wasm, and for some reason no matter what i do adelay does not do anything, but this weird reverse approach does

Answer (score 2):

Order matters. I have tried the sox command above and the ffmpeg command below and it works

```
ffmpeg -shortest -i silence.wav -acodec pcm_s16le -i out.mov -vcodec copy -strict -2 vid_with_sound.mov
```

Comment: Where does order matter—what is the wrong order and what problems does it cause?

Comment: ffmpeg command line parameters order matters. It won't work right otherwise