# ffmpeg create blank screen with text video

Tags: video, text, ffmpeg

I would like to create a video consisting of some text. The video will only be 0.5 seconds long. The background should just be some colour, I am able to create such video from a photo, but cant find anywhere how this could be done without a photo, just using text to create such video.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

## drawtext vs subtitles

This can be done using the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) or [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filters.

*drawtext* is simpler, but *subtitles* has much better styling and timing options. *subtitles* can automatically wrap the text while *drawtext* cannot.

---

## drawtext filter examples

### Add text to solid color background

[image]

Using the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) filter for the background and the [drawtext](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawtext) filter for the text. Example for a 320x240, 10 second, 25 fps, blue background. Text is size 30, colored white, and centered.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=320x240:duration=10:rate=25:color=blue -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='Stack Overflow'" output.mp4
```

- The `duration=10` will make a 10 second duration output.
- See the [list of supported color names and how to use a hex code to set color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Color).

### With audio file

Same as above, but video will automatically match audio duration by removing `duration=10` and adding `-shortest`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=320x240:rate=25:color=blue -i audio.m4a -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='Stack Overflow'" -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

### With a transparent box behind text

Another example with a white box behind the text at 25% opacity with 5 pixel padding:

[image]

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=red:s=320x240:d=10 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:box=1:boxborderw=5:boxcolor=white@0.25:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='Stack Overflow'" output.mp4
```

### Multiple lines

[image] [image]
<sub>It's easier to center the two lines with multiple drawtext instances (left image). Right image is from the external file and line break examples.</sub>

**There are 3 methods.** You can chain together two drawtext filters, or reference an external text file with the `textfile` option, or add the line break in the command.

Alternatively, see the example below using the subtitles filter. This filter will automatically wrap long text.

#### Method 1: Multiple `drawtext` instances

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=green:s=320x240:d=10 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h-text_h)/2:text='Stack',drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h+text_h)/2:text='Overflow'" output.mp4
```

#### Method 2: External text file

The contents of the text file, `text.txt`, looks like this:

```
Stack
Overflow
```

The `ffmpeg` command:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=green:s=320x240:d=0.5 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:textfile=text.txt" output.mp4
```

#### Method 3: Line break in command

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=green:s=320x240:d=0.5 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/path/to/font.ttf:fontsize=30:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text='Stack
Overflow'" output.mp4
```

### Positions

- Top left: `x=0:y=0` (with 10 pixel padding `x=10:y=10`)
- Top center: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=0` (with 10 px padding `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=10`)
- Top right: `x=w-tw:y=0` (with 10 px padding: `x=w-tw-10:y=10`)
- Centered: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2`
- Bottom left: `x=0:y=h-th` (with 10 px padding: `x=10:y=h-th-10`)
- Bottom center: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th` (with 10 px padding: `x=(w-text_w)/2:y=h-th-10`)
- Bottom right: `x=w-tw:y=h-th` (with 10 px padding: `x=w-tw-10:y=h-th-10`)

---

## subtitles filter example with audio

Using the [color](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#color) filter for the background and the [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) filter for the text.

First, create [SRT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.srt) (SubRip) file. This example sets the duration to 10 hours. The duration doesn't really matter: it just needs to be longer than the audio file duration.

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 10:00:00,000
Stack Overflow
```

Then run `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=256x144:rate=15:color=blue -i "Audio File.m4a" -vf "subtitles=subtitles.srt:force_style='Alignment=10,Fontsize=30'" -c:a copy -movflags +faststart -shortest output.mp4
```

- Alternatively, use [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/) to create [ASS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubStation_Alpha#Advanced_SubStation_Alpha) (Advanced SubStation Alpha) subtitles and you won't have to use `force_style`. Downside is that ASS is a much more complicated format than SRT.
- If you want to use `force_style` refer to the `Format` and `Style` lines in an ASS file to get an idea of how to use more `force_style` options, and also see [Aegisub Manual - Ass Tags](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/) for advanced formatting.

---

## Output image instead of video

If you want an image output instead replace `output.mp4` with `-frames:v 1 output.png`.

Comment: just to add that you can get a solid from from hex code like: color=c=0xff0000

Comment: @nicruo That's probably worth mentioning. I added a link to the list of supported color names which also contains info on hex usage.

Comment: But how do you put two texts in there?

Comment: @ethanjyx I just added three examples to place multiple lines of text.

Comment: I exactly need this command to be executed in android. Would you mind providing full code  to execute in android here.

Comment: @DilaGurung I have no Android experience, but the command should look similar except you may have to remove any quotes.

Comment: Suppose  I want to add style..how would i specify it. ":style=Bold:" is not working in my case.

Comment: @DilaGurung That requires your ffmpeg to be built with `--enable-libfontconfig`. Otherwise, consider using [subtitles](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) instead of drawtext.

Comment: For any others using this method to `concat` with other videos, be sure to [add an empty audio track](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368151/adding-silent-audio-in-ffmpeg) or your output will have no audio.

Comment: Awesome! But how do I add an image to this video? Or better, maybe 2 image, one first half, second video second half, the text all the time?

Comment: @tobidude See [How to add watermark with ffmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10920872/) and see the [`enable` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Timeline-editing) (see [more examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bffmpeg%5D+overlay+enable+is%3Aanswer)).

Comment: Great examples, is it possible that we use dynamic text for subtitles or using drawtext to wrap text according to video width and height? I have asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70936224/ffmpeg-add-subtitles-to-live-stream-dynamically) but I did not get any answers yet.

Comment: How do I create text with transparent background and save it as png?

Comment: The correct link to ass tags: https://aegisite.vercel.app/docs/latest/ass_tags/ @llogan Please edit in the post. I am not able to do that.