# Merge Multiple Videos using node fluent ffmpeg

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg

requirement is to read all the files in the directory and merge them.
        I am using node fluent-ffmpeg to achieve this.
        First of all reading all the files in the directory appending concatenating the string by adding `.input`.

```
var finalresult="E:/ETV/videos/finalresult.mp4"
outputresult : It consists of all the files read in the directory.

/*Javascript*/
MergeVideo(outputresult);
function MergeVideo(outputresult){
console.log("in merge video");
var videostring = "";

for(i=1;i<5;i++)
    {
videostring = videostring+".input("+"'"+outputresult[i]+"'"+")";
}
console.log("Video String"+videostring);
    var proc = ffmpeg()+videostring
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('files have  succesfully Merged');
        })
    .on('error', function(err) {
      console.log('an error happened: ' + err.message);
    })
    .mergeToFile(finalresult);
}
```

It gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Object .input('ETV 22-02-2015 1-02-25 AM.mp4').input('ETV 22-02-2015
9-33-15 PM.mp4').input('ETV 22-02-2015 9-32-46 AM.mp4').input('ETV 22-02-2015 8-
32-44 AM.mp4') has no method 'on'
    at MergeVideo (D:\Development\Node\node-fluent-ffmpeg-master\node-fluent-ffm
peg-master\examples\demo.js:140:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Development\Node\node-fluent-ffmpeg-master\node-fl
uent-ffmpeg-master\examples\demo.js:129:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 20):

Try this

```
var fluent_ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

var mergedVideo = fluent_ffmpeg();
var videoNames = ['./video1.mp4', './video2.mp4'];

videoNames.forEach(function(videoName){
    mergedVideo = mergedVideo.addInput(videoName);
});

mergedVideo.mergeToFile('./mergedVideo.mp4', './tmp/')
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Comment: I am getting invalid input index error when invoking mergeToFile method. can you let me know any aspect to be verified?

Comment: getting  Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0

Comment: @Mikel please help me

Comment: Does it work in 2022? I've only changed var fluent_ffmepg to import and function(~) to arrow function. but It doesn't work for me

Answer (score 3):

```
var fluent_ffmpeg = require("fluent-ffmpeg");

var mergedVideo = fluent_ffmpeg();
var videoNames = ['./video1.mp4', './video2.mp4'];

videoNames.forEach(function(videoName){
    mergedVideo = mergedVideo.addInput(videoName);
});

mergedVideo.mergeToFile('./mergedVideo.mp4', './tmp/')
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('Error ' + err.message);
})
.on('end', function() {
    console.log('Finished!');
});
```

This issue happening getting Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 3 on filter Parsed_concat_0

Because one of the file doesn't have audio in it.

Answer (score 1):

answered here:
[adding silent audio in ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368151/adding-silent-audio-in-ffmpeg)

i tried to use `fluent-ffmpeg` but couldn't make it :/ After hours of debugging I switched to the native solution.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31563738)