# fluent-ffmpeg from an array of input files

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ffmpeg, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to use `fluent-ffmpeg` to create a video of last n images of a directory, or database entries.

Which is the correct syntax?

These are my tries:

**Mimic shell command**

```
ffmpeg()
  .addInput('ls *png | tail -n 17')
  .inputOptions("-pattern_type glob")
  .output("output.mp4").run()
```

but it does not accept shell commands;

**space - separated paths**

```
ffmpeg()
  .addInput('a*.png b*.png ')
  .inputOptions("-pattern_type glob")
  .output("output.mp4").run()
```

but it does not accept list of files separated by spaces;

**Array of image paths**

```
ffmpeg()
  .addInput(array) // ['aa.png', 'a1.png',,,'bbb.png']
  .inputOptions("-pattern_type glob")
  .output("output.mp4").run()
```

but it does not accept arrays.

**EDIT:**

Also, from [Merge Multiple Videos using node fluent ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877848/merge-multiple-videos-using-node-fluent-ffmpeg), I am able to add multiple inputs using an array of files as

```
var ffmpeg= require('fluent-ffmpeg');
var f=ffmpeg() 
pngarr.forEach(p => f.input(p)) /// pngarr is my array of png paths
```

But running

```
f.output("./output.mp4").run()
```

I obtain just a video of 0 seconds containing the first png of the list.

Answer (score 7):

The ffmpeg methods are chainable, so you could use a reducer like so:

```
var chainedInputs = inputlist.reduce((result, inputItem) => result.addInput(inputItem), ffmpeg());
```

Your last edit nearly did the same thing, but it keeps calling            .input() on the same level instead of on top of the previous

Comment: But `chainedInputs.output("./output.mp4").run() ` still returns a 0 seonds video containing the first png of the list

Comment: The reduce method works for me, but I have so many input videos that the resulting command was too long and could not be executed. Is there a way to input a text file with a list of video files? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51034956/inputing-a-list-of-files-for-concatenation-with-node-js-module-fluent-ffmpeg