# Can I add silent audio based on another video, to a video created from a PNG loop

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

We have videos that we transcode to h.264, but COPY the original audio track (they all vary).  We are now trying to prepend a 10 second disclaimer before the original video begins.  Apparently the audio tracks of the two videos must be the same, so I'm trying to add a silent audio track to the generated video based on the audio track of the video it will be concatenated with.

From other questions, I've learned to add `-f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100`, but this results in garbled audio when the concatenation occurs.  So using ffprobe, I would like to get whatever audio properties are needed and use them in the prepending video.

So the question is: How can I specify the specific audio track settings I want/need when creating the 10 second video?

**FFMpeg to create 10 second disclaimer**

`ffmpeg.exe -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -loop 1 -i disclaimer.png -filter:v "fade=out:st=8:d=2" -c:v libx264 -t 10 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 29.97 disclaimer.mp4`

**FFProbe**

```
ffprobe -show_format -show_streams OriginalVideo.mp4
ffprobe version N-73975-gda8b70b Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libdcadec --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
  libavutil      54. 28.100 / 54. 28.100
  libavcodec     56. 52.100 / 56. 52.100
  libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 27.100 /  5. 27.100
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'OriginalVideo.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    title           : 343520959333629
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
  Duration: 00:00:24.56, start: 0.160998, bitrate: 245 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 640x400 [SAR 1615:1616 DAR 323:202], 194 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (HE-AACv2) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 47 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[STREAM]
index=0
codec_name=h264
codec_long_name=H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10
profile=High
codec_type=video
codec_time_base=1/50
codec_tag_string=avc1
codec_tag=0x31637661
width=640
height=400
coded_width=640
coded_height=400
has_b_frames=2
sample_aspect_ratio=1615:1616
display_aspect_ratio=323:202
pix_fmt=yuv420p
level=31
color_range=N/A
color_space=unknown
color_transfer=unknown
color_primaries=unknown
chroma_location=left
timecode=N/A
refs=5
is_avc=1
nal_length_size=4
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=25/1
avg_frame_rate=25/1
time_base=1/90000
start_pts=0
start_time=0.000000
duration_ts=2181600
duration=24.240000
bit_rate=194642
max_bit_rate=N/A
bits_per_raw_sample=8
nb_frames=606
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=VideoHandler
[/STREAM]
[STREAM]
index=1
codec_name=aac
codec_long_name=AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)
profile=HE-AACv2
codec_type=audio
codec_time_base=1/44100
codec_tag_string=mp4a
codec_tag=0x6134706d
sample_fmt=fltp
sample_rate=44100
channels=2
channel_layout=stereo
bits_per_sample=0
id=N/A
r_frame_rate=0/0
avg_frame_rate=0/0
time_base=1/44100
start_pts=-7100
start_time=-0.160998
duration_ts=1083268
duration=24.563900
bit_rate=47738
max_bit_rate=48053
bits_per_raw_sample=N/A
nb_frames=526
nb_read_frames=N/A
nb_read_packets=N/A
DISPOSITION:default=1
DISPOSITION:dub=0
DISPOSITION:original=0
DISPOSITION:comment=0
DISPOSITION:lyrics=0
DISPOSITION:karaoke=0
DISPOSITION:forced=0
DISPOSITION:hearing_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:visual_impaired=0
DISPOSITION:clean_effects=0
DISPOSITION:attached_pic=0
TAG:language=und
TAG:handler_name=SoundHandler
[/STREAM]
[FORMAT]
filename=OriginalVideo.mp4
nb_streams=2
nb_programs=0
format_name=mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2
format_long_name=QuickTime / MOV
start_time=-0.160998
duration=24.564000
size=753253
bit_rate=245319
probe_score=100
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
TAG:title=343520959333629
TAG:encoder=Lavf56.40.101
[/FORMAT]
```

Comment: As I mentioned in your related question you need to either: 1) Encode `disclaimer.mp4` audio as HE-AACv2 using libfdk_aac encoder (which your `ffmpeg` was not compiled to support) or use an external HE-AACv2 encoder, or 2) Re-encode the audio of `OriginalVideo.mp4` to LC-AAC (regular, normal, everyday AAC) using `-c:a aac` (which your `ffmpeg` supports).

Comment: I apologize, most of this A/V stuff is over my head...#2 is not an option because of quality loss in the result, and #1 looks like a journey that I'm grossly underqualified for.  Thank you though, I DO appreciate you taking the time to give me the options.

Comment: Seems like you are at an impasse then. You can't do #1 with your current ffmpeg because of a lack of libfdk_aac in your ffmpeg, but also you ruled out #2. Did you try re-encoding the audio of `OriginalVideo.mp4` and listening? Might not be as bad as you assume. Did you create `OriginalVideo.mp4`?

Comment: You "forced" me to revisit re-encoding the audio of the original video.  It was a long night of learning all the options and syntax of ffmpeg and audio codecs, but I finally got it done.  "No Pain No Gain" I guess.  I wish you'd posted an answer - you deserve SOME kind of credit for solving this problem for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenation has two requirements:

- All inputs must have the same number and type of streams.
- All streams must have the same parameters.

`disclaimer.mp4` has no audio. `OriginalVideo.mp4` has HE-AACv2 audio.

So you will need to [create a silent audio stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12375018/1109017) for `disclaimer.mp4` and encode it as HE-AACv2. However, this may be problematic because the only HE-AACv2 audio encoder supported by FFmpeg is libfdk_aac which your `ffmpeg` build does not support. Alternatively you can look into using a different, standalone encoder.

Or create the silent audio as LC-AAC (the command AAC variant) and re-encode the `OriginalVideo.mp4` as LC-AAC.