# How to append 2 seconds of silence to an existing movie MP4 with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I would like to append 2 seconds of silence to an existing video using ffmpeg.
I would like to keep the last frame displayed while the 2 seconds of video playsback not a black screen.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes the MP4 has audio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [tpad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tpad) and [apad](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#apad) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v]tpad=stop_mode=clone:stop_duration=2[v];[0:a]apad=pad_dur=2[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mp4
```

A faster, but less compatible method is to stream copy the video and use the apad filter if your player and output container format supports dissimilar stream durations:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]apad=pad_dur=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output.mp4
```

If in doubt use the first command.

Comment: If was want to have the same thing but at the start of the video then what needs to be done ?