# HLS never plays on iPhone with Nginx fed by ffmpeg. Works on Desktop Safari and iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, nginx, http-live-streaming, nginx-rtmp

I am live streaming a Camera via RTMP to a Nginx RTMP server like so:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://user:pass@192.168.1.XXX/ -f image2 -stream_loop -1 -re -i /tmp/overlay.png -filter_complex "overlay" -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -profile baseline -pix_fmt yuv420p -an -f flv -rtmp_live live -s 1280x720 rtmp://remote.server.com:1935/show/stream
```

My Nginx Server config:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    # sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/myccam-access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/myccam-error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 8080;

        location ~ \.(mp4|m4a|m4v|mov)$ {
        add_header content_disposition filename=$request_uri;
        add_header accept_ranges bytes;
        }


        location /hls {
        # Disable cache
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;

        # CORS setup
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length';
            add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
        add_header Last-Modified "";

        # allow CORS preflight requests
        if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
            add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
            add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
            return 204;
        }

        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }

        root /tmp/;
        }
    }
}


rtmp {
    server {
        listen 1935; # Listen on standard RTMP port
        chunk_size 4000;

        application show {
            live on;
            hls on;
            hls_fragment_naming system;
            hls_fragment 1s;
            hls_path /tmp/hls;
            hls_continuous on;

        hls_variant _720p2628kbs BANDWIDTH=2628000;

        }
    }
}
```

I proxy this setup through a running Apache server which already has valid SSL certificates. I can access the stream like this via VLC without issue. `https://myserver.com/CameraName/hls/stream.m3u8`

To view in browser I am using this HTML admittedly borrowed from someone else:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Camera</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            background: none !important;
            overflow: hidden;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        video {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
        }

        .video-container {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh
        }
    </style>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

    <script>
        function waitForPublishedStream(showMsg) {
            if (typeof showMsg === 'undefined') showMsg = true;

            $.get('https://myserver.com/CameraName/hls/stream.m3u8', function (response) {

                if (showMsg) {
                    $('.container-loader .alert-warning').html('Pieslēdzamies kamerai..')
                }

                if (response.state == 'success') {
                    if (response.published) {
                        document.location.reload(true)
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            waitForPublishedStream();
                        }, 2000)
                    }
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

            <div class="video-container">
            <video id="video" autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" controls="controls" playsinline="" src="https://myserver.com/CameraName/hls/stream.m3u8">
                <source src="https://myserver.com/CameraName/hls/stream.m3u8" type="application/vnd.apple.mpegurl">
            </video>
        </div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        const video = document.getElementById('video');

        if (Hls.isSupported()) {

            const hls = new Hls();

            hls.loadSource('https://myserver.com/CameraName/hls/stream.m3u8');
            hls.attachMedia(video);
            hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
                video.play();
            });
        }
    })
</script>
</body></html>
```

This works on every device I have tested it on EXCEPT the iPhone. Which is the most important platform for it to work on. On the iPhone the stream just loads forever without displaying anything. The debugger shows that the device is downloading the .ts files correctly. Interestingly the stream will load about 10% of the time if I pop it fullscreen and fast forward the stream. The timestamp on the player shows something way off when this happens. Something like -11:21:42. I suspect this issue may have something to do with the PTS being fed from ffmpeg.

Apples `mediastreamvalidator` CLI tool shows that some of the .ts files are being kicked back as 404. But I have not been able to reproduce this on any browser debugger. Any help is greatly appreciated :)

References:

---

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690298

https://github.com/arut/nginx-rtmp-module/issues/1656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by moving away from Nginx entirely and using [node-media-server](https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server) instead

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but I had the same issue and spend a good few hours solving it. So maybe my answer is useful to someone.

As with OP (and with the same configuration: nginx and hls.js), my HLS-stream was loading but never played on my iPhone (every other device not being Apple worked). It turned out Apple was expecting audio to be present in the stream, and my webcam provides no audio. I solved it adding an empty audio channel to the stream when converting from webcam to HLS:

```
ffmpeg -i camerastream -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=24000 -c:a aac -shortest
```

This resulted in a HLS stream **with** a very lightweight audio-channel and now the stream was working perfect on any device, including the iPhone.

[The answer was found here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12368151/1685196) and the [Apple specs are found here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure that `Hls.isSupported()` resolves to `false` for iPhones. It doesn't for iPads and Macs. The crux is that "[HLS.js relies on HTML5 video and MediaSource Extensions for playback.](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/issues/4354#issuecomment-947134340)" Which is not supported by iPhone Safari.